# my app don't working in android 6.0 platform

Tags: android

I did an SMS application. My app working from platform 10 to platform 22. But doesn't work on platform 23 (so android 6 platform). I'm using Android studio. Why my app don't work on android 23 platform?

(Note: On Android 23 platform my app enjoying "stopped error")

Comment: We need stacktrace (-s). Also, have you read [this](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html)?

Answer (score 1):

Is your app targeting V23?

If you are targeting V23 take in account that SMS permissions are considered danger ones and you have to [ask for permission at runtime](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/requesting.html).

If it isn't your issue please provide a detailed stacktrace of your crash.

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 23

Answer (score 0):

In android 6.0 SMS, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission get from user run time

check follow url for your reference

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                1000);

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                2000);

        Toast.makeText(this, permissionCheck1 + " Permission " + permissionCheck, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Where I do write this code?

Comment: after calling "requestPermissions" to shows popup screen. after user select ALLOW after that call SMS function it will work.

below function you can check permission is granted or not and check what user is selected 

int permissionCheck1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

sorry for my poor english

Comment: call this functions before SMS functions

Answer (score 0):

I think you have update your SDK first to API level 23, and the rebuilt your project and Run the App...

Hope this will works for you...